# Using Between on only time portion of dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads WHERE create_date > '06:00' AND create_date < '18:00';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads WHERE create_date > '06:00' AND create_date < '18:00';
```

However, the create_date column looks like '2011-08-26 10:18:01' and i want to find everything between just those time periods, regardless of the day.

How can I just query the time from the create_date values?

How would also find all values not within those time periods?
NOT BETWEEN ....

Comment: Just a note, using `TIME()` will affect the usefulness of your indexes as it's doing a computation on each row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the time from the date, you can use the [`TIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) function.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads WHERE TIME(create_date) > '06:00' AND create_date < '18:00';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads WHERE TIME(create_date) > '06:00' AND create_date < '18:00';
```

To find times outside this range, just invert everything in your where clauses.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads WHERE TIME(create_date) < '06:00' AND create_date > '18:00';
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads WHERE TIME(create_date) < '06:00' AND create_date > '18:00';
```

Comment: Thanks. However, the inverse symbols don't seem to work. I end up with 0, which isn't possible in my database.

Comment: Sorry, ORs should have been ANDs.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`TIME()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) to return only the time portion of a `DATETIME` column.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads WHERE TIME(create_date) > '06:00' AND TIME(create_date) < '18:00';
```

To find the values outside these time periods, use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads WHERE TIME(create_date) <= '06:00' AND TIME(create_date) >= '18:00';
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that create_date is of type DATETIME, to extract the time part only use TIME(create_date).

And yes, NOT BETWEEN will get the inverse set.

Answer (score 2):

You can just cast to a TIME:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads WHERE TIME(create_date) > '06:00' AND TIME(create_date) < '18:00';
```